# Which install docs to use for two node WSO2 IS installation?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am performing the initial setup of WSO2 Identity Server for a small organization.  We will not have a large number of transactions but we want high availability and reliability.  We have decided on a two node “cluster” or “active/active” configuration.  We have been testing with WSO2 IS v 5.3.0.  I am having a problem sorting through all the documentation and determining which install documents to use.

I found this document for WSO2 IS v 5.2.0 that specifically covers “Clustering Identity Server.”  This document references a detailed database setup procedure that appears to be out of date.  It also covers the configuration of Hazelcast along with editing other XML files.  The clustering install guide is located here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+Identity+Server+5.1.0+and+5.2.0

Then I found this newer install guide that covers the “active/active” configuration.  This document is titled “Deployment for Small and Medium-sized Enterprises” and is located here https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS5xx/Deployment+for+Small+and+Medium-sized+Enterprises#DeploymentforSmallandMedium-sizedEnterprises-Active/Active

This new document contains a very simple procedure for setting up an active/active configuration that looks like it will meet our needs.  My concern is that this second document does not cover any of the specific database setup that is covered in the clustering document.  This second document does not cover the hazelcast setup or other clustering configurations.  My guess is the "active/active" setup is not the same as the "clustered" architecture.

Can someone clarify the difference between the "clustered" and "active/active" architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deployment pattern 1 in [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Deployment+Patterns) document is your requirement as I understood. It explains how to configure a High available clustered deployment. There is no difference in the two terms.

I think [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Setting+Up+Deployment+Pattern+1) is the documentation you are looking for.